# Writing Hex To Console Using NSString

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, syntax, hex

I'm trying to write all the hex values, from 0 - 255 in a for loop. It's not printing in hex. I think the `%x` is what is causing the issue.

```
int i=0;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        [_d writeXYZ:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", i]];

    }
```

Does anyone know the proper syntax to display 0-255 in hex?

When I do it like this:

```
        int i=0;

        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%x", i);
        }
```

It runs perfectly, so it looks like my issue is within `NSString`.

Comment: You don't know how to write all the hex values, huh!?  I don't even know what _d or writeXYZ are.

Comment: Just pretend like it's an NSLog.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @OralB: You still haven't explained what output you are getting when you use `writeXYZ:`. All you've said is what it isn't doing (printing in hex).

Comment: It prints gibberish, I'm not near my computer but it did not print in the given order. I'm not trying to debug it, just find out how the community would approach writing hex using an NSString like I tried above.

Comment: Split your code up a little. Change `[_d writeXYZ:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", i]];` to two lines: `NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", i];` and `[_d writeXYZ:hex];`. You will see that `hex` is fine. This means your `writeXYZ:` method is where the problem lies.